# Find value if value is part of Enum value

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I have enum like the following and I wonder if I have a variable like **string = March** 
there is a simple way via API to find if the value (March )is part of the enum

```
public enum Month
{
    NotSet = 0,
    January = 1,
    February = 2,
    March = 3,
    April = 4,
    May = 5,
    June = 6,
    July = 7,
    August = 8,
    September = 9,
    October = 10,
    November = 11,
    December = 12
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
Month result;
if(System.Enum.TryParse(value, true, out result)) {
    // is defined
}
```

where the `true` there controls case-sensitivity (or not).

(note this is actually `TryParse<Month>(...)`, but the compiler infers the `<Month>` from the `out result`, since `result` is defined as `Month`)

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to find out whether a certain value is defined in an enum, use [`Enum.IsDefined`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
bool isDefined = Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Month), "March")
```

---

If you want to parse the value, have a look at [`Enum.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Converts the string representation of the name or numeric value of one or more enumerated constants to an equivalent enumerated object. The return value indicates whether the conversion succeeded.

You can use the following overload …

```
public static bool TryParse<TEnum>(
    string value,
    bool ignoreCase,
    out TEnum result
)
```

… like this:

```
Month month;
if (Enum.TryParse<Month>("March", true, out month)) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about using [`Enum.GetNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getnames.aspx)

> Retrieves an array of the names of the constants in a specified
>   enumeration.

Like;

```
bool b = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Month)).Contains("March");
```

Or as Raphaël *[mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767259/find-value-if-value-is-part-of-enum-value/19767302#comment29377891_19767302)*;

```
if(Enum.GetName(typeof(Month), "March") != null)
```

Comment: +1, or `Enum.GetName(typeof(Month), "March") != null`